# After install CSV Plugin in Android Studio 4.0 Not able to Open Project Setting and build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

This is the first time I've encountered this issue with Studio 4.0. Project and app-level files not able to open, below some other file which not able to open:

Android Studio 4.0 - .csv file Not open, displays nothing.
                   - .java file not open.
                   - .kt file not open.

Has anyone else seen this behavior before? And solutions? Advice would be appreciated.

I have used this plugin for CSV file read https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10037-csv-plugin without this plugin Studio working fine.

Comment: same here I installed a plugin in android studio I can't open any java file or settings

Comment: After I installed CSV plugin I can't open Android Studio's Preferences and SDK manager

Answer (score 4):

Go to the folder:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins
```

On Linux:

```
~/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins/
```

…and delete the csv plugin folder.

This will solve all of the problems. For any other issue, just go to the File menu and sync the project with gradle files.

Comment: I delete all file in plugin but I cannot open setting in android studio. the color of code is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on **MacOS** with ***AndroidStudio2021.1***,then I deleted the following folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/plugins/CSV
```

But still not working for me, then I deleted whole folder of AndroidStudio2021.1 directory path is:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1
```

or You can only delete folder of plugin, It might be work also.

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/plugins
```

Comment: This solved my problem for Android Studio 2021.2.1 as well!

Answer (score 0):

For people using Ubuntu 20.04 and having Android Studio 4.1 installed manually (no snap), you'll find the folder under `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on MacOS with **Android Studio 4.1**. I deleted the following folder and it works now:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue, I have used one CSV file into my Android Studio project and downloaded the **CSV plugin** after that while building gradle it was showing Lint Infrastructure Error.
Then, I have uninstalled the **CSV plugin** then everything is fine. (Hope this answer would be helpful to the guys who are facing similar type of error)